# The order of an element of a group $G$

Tags: group-theory

Exercise

Let $G$ be any group and $x=a^k$, where $a \in G$ is an element of order $n$ and $k$ is a natural number. Find the $ord(x)$.

My candidate for $ord(a^k)$ is $\dfrac{n}{(n:k)}$. By elevating $a^k$ we have $$(a^k)^\frac{n}{(n:k)}=a^{k\frac{n}{(n:k)}}=(a^n)^{\frac{n}{(n:k)}}=1^{\frac{n}{(n:k)}}.$$

By definition of $ord(a^k)$, we have $ord(a^k)|\dfrac{n}{(n:k)}$, so $ord(a^k)\leq\dfrac{n}{(n:k)}$

I got stuck trying to show the other inequality. Maybe the problem is that my candidate is not the correct one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notation $(n:k)$.  What does it stand for?

Comment: It is the greatest common divisor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your candidate is correct. Let $p=ord(a^k)$ then $a^{kp}=e$ so $n|kp$ and then $\frac{n}{(n:k)}|\frac{k}{(n:k)}p$ and since $\frac{n}{(n:k)}$ and $\frac{k}{(n:k)}$ are coprime so by the Euclid's lemma we have $\frac{n}{(n:k)}|p$.